# How to highlight Continents and Country in Kendo UI Map?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-map

As per one of my requirement my client wants to highlight continent and country based on some condition ? I have searched but i am not able to find out on how to implement the same in Kendo Map ?

Comment: Where's your map coming from? Is it an image/tile like this example(http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/map/index) or shape data like this(http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/map/geojson)...I think you will need the shape data so that you know the exact border shape to highlight, whereas the tile are just images(which you may be able to super-impose shape data on top).

Comment: Hello Stephen...... First of all thanks for your reply. Moving on to the question that i have raised - I am using image/tile based map [a basic map] currently and on that i want to highlight certain continents and countries. Is there any plugin's inbuilt function which can be used to attain the same or some other approach has to taken?